# iotovity croos compilation fails.

Tags: arm, ubuntu-16.04, iotivity

Greetings

I am new to iotivity and following the iotivity wiki guidelines for understanding and building framework.(on Ubuntu 16.04)

AIM - For ARM Cross Compilation. We are following the below Iotivity link.

https://wiki.iotivity.org/iotivity_porting_to_arm_based_platforms?s[]=arm&s[]=based&s[]=platforms

Described below Step 4 as mention in the link .

We are using arm-linux-gnueabi compiler which support build for our tager Artik 520 - ARM Cortex A7 processer.

4) Download the UUID Header/Libraries for arm architecture from Internet or from linkuuid-arm.zip. Place the UUID Headers/Libraries inside IoTivity folder (For Eg: iotivity/extlibs/). Update the CPPPATH/LIBPATH for UUID Headers/Libraries in required SConscript

As describe above i have followed the steps. 
 -Issue is the uuid-arm folder doesn't have any defulat SConscript when unzip(only header and lib folder) and it is not Cleary mention which is the required SConscript to add below lines. The uuid.so is present in the uuid-arm lib folder.below are the lines which are mention need to be added.i am confused on this which will be the required Sconscripts and how to debug this. Kindly help on this.

```
  For E.g.: env.AppendUnique(CPPPATH = [ '<uuid header path>'])

            env.AppendUnique(LIBPATH =  ['<uuid Library Path>'])

            env.AppendUnique(LIBS = ['uuid'])

            {{:arm_uuid_path.png?200|}} ----->  This line itself is a syntax error to add anywhere.
```

Build Command

scons TARGET_OS=linux TARGET_ARCH=arm TARGET_TRANSPORT=IP SECURED=0 RELEASE=1 TC_PREFIX=arm-linux-gnueabi- TC_PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabi/bin

ERROR

scons: Building targets ...

scons: building associated VariantDir targets: out/linux/arm/release Linking out/linux/arm/release/resource/csdk/connectivity/src/libconnectivity_abstraction.so

/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/5/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -luuid

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

scons: *** [out/linux/arm/release/resource/csdk/connectivity/src/libconnectivity_abstraction.so] Error 1

scons: building terminated because of errors

Thanks for help..

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like the path to the uuid library is not updated properly in the scons file.

Can you please share your changes in the scons file, specifically the below lines.

```
        env.AppendUnique(CPPPATH = [ '<uuid header path>'])

        env.AppendUnique(LIBPATH =  ['<uuid Library Path>'])

        env.AppendUnique(LIBS = ['uuid'])
```

I hope you have updated the `['< uuid Library path>']` with your absolute path, which may be `/root/workspace/iotivity/extlibs/uuid`

---

Agreed,  `{{:arm_uuid_path.png?200|}}` is not a proper scons syntax. It looks like a webpage error to me, instead of the image file, just the path is included

Comment: Thats what my concern is  in the iotivity page , it is mention add these lines in required SConscripts files. I am not able to find the accurate files which all required. however by looking the   building  erro - associated VariantDir targets: out/linux/arm/release Linking out/linux/arm/release/resource/csdk/connectivity/src/libconnectivity_abstraction.so  , i try to add these lines in csdk and  connectivity SConscripts but it fails too with same error.